# Errors when editting existing WP8 project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, xaml, windows-phone-8, compiler-errors

So I am just starting out with this stuff and have run into some strife. There was a pivot soundboard application that I needed to change into a series of panorama pages but have the same functionality.

I have finished all the xaml and c# appropriately but I think because I had to create a new MainPage and delete the older one I have created several errors. I suspect they all have a similar cause so I will just provide three.

> Error 1   The type 'SoundBoard.MainPage' already contains a definition
>   for 'LayoutRoot'  \SoundBoard\obj\Debug\Cartoons.g.cs
>
> Error 30  The name 'AudioPlayer' does not exist in the current
>   context   \SoundBoard\Cartoons.xaml.cs
>
> Error 7   Type 'SoundBoard.MainPage' already defines a member called
>   'InitializeComponent' with the same parameter types
>   \SoundBoard\obj\Debug\Cartoons.g.cs

I'll link my current MainPage and Cartoons and hopefully you guys can help me out.

MainPage.xaml:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage
    x:Class="SoundBoard.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DataContext="{d:DesignData SampleData/SampleData.xaml}"
    FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
    FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
    Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
    SupportedOrientations="Portrait"  Orientation="Portrait"
    shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True">

    <!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28">
            <TextBlock Text="SoundBoard" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"/>
            <TextBlock Text="Categories" Margin="9,-7,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>
        </StackPanel>

        <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
        <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
            <Button Content="Warnings" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="244,304,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="160" Width="182" Background="Red" Click="Button_Click_3"/>
            <Button Content="Taunts" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="27,304,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="160" Width="182" Background="Red" Click="Button_Click_2"/>
            <Button Content="Cartoons" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="244,123,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="160" Width="182" Background="Red" Click="Button_Click_1"/>
            <Button Content="Animals" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="27,123,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="160" Width="182" Background="Red" Click="Button_Click"/>

        </Grid>
    </Grid>

</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using Microsoft.Phone.Shell;

namespace SoundBoard
{
    public partial class FirstPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        public FirstPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Animals.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
        }

        private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Cartoons.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
        }

        private void Button_Click_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Taunts.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
        }

        private void Button_Click_3(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Warnings.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
        }
    }
}
```

Cartoons.xaml:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage
    x:Class="SoundBoard.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DataContext="{d:DesignData SampleData/SampleData.xaml}"
    FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
    FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
    Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
    SupportedOrientations="Portrait"  Orientation="Portrait"
    shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True">


    <!--LayoutRoot contains the root grid where all other page content is placed-->
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <phone:Panorama Title="{Binding Path=LocalizedResources.ApplicationTitle,
            Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}">

            <!--Panorama item one-->
            <phone:PanoramaItem Header="Cartoons">
                <Grid>
                    <Image HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="431" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="400" Source="/Assets/cartoon.jpg"/>
                </Grid>
            </phone:PanoramaItem>

            <!--Panorama item two-->
            <phone:PanoramaItem Header="Sounds">
                <phone:LongListSelector
                    Margin="0,0,-12,0" 
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Cartoons.Items}"
                    LayoutMode="Grid"
                    GridCellSize="150,150"                  
                    >
                    <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid Background="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}">

                                <Grid VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
                                      Width="40" Height="40" Margin="0,6,6,0">
                                    <Ellipse Stroke="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}" 
                                             StrokeThickness="3" />
                                    <Image Source="Assets/AppBar/Play.png" />


                                </Grid>

                                <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}"
                                               Margin="6,0,0,6"/>

                                </StackPanel>

                            </Grid>

                        </DataTemplate>
                    </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
                </phone:LongListSelector>
            </phone:PanoramaItem>

            <!--Panorama item three-->
            <phone:PanoramaItem Header="Record">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
                        <MediaElement x:Name="AudioPlayer" AutoPlay="False" />

                        <StackPanel>
                            <ToggleButton Content="Record"
                                          Checked="RecordAudioChecked"
                                          Unchecked="RecordAudioUnchecked"/>
                            <Grid Width="200" 
                                  Height="200" 
                                  Name="ReelGrid"
                                  RenderTransformOrigin=".5,.5">
                                <Grid.RenderTransform>
                                    <CompositeTransform />
                                </Grid.RenderTransform>


                                <Ellipse Fill="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}" />

                                <Ellipse Height="20"
                                         Width="20"
                                         Fill="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}" />
                                <Rectangle Height="20"
                                           Width="20"
                                           Margin="0,20,0,20"
                                           VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                                           Fill="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}" />

                                <Rectangle Height="20"
                                           Width="20"
                                           Margin="0,20,0,20"
                                           VerticalAlignment="Bottom" 
                                           Fill="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}" />

                                <Rectangle Height="20"
                                           Width="20"
                                           Margin="0,0,20,0"
                                           HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
                                           Fill="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}" />

                                <Rectangle Height="20"
                                           Width="20"
                                           Margin="20,0,0,0"
                                           HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                                           Fill="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}" />

                            </Grid>
                            <Button Name="PlayAudio" Content="Play" Click="PlayAudioClick" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </phone:PanoramaItem>

        </phone:Panorama>
    </Grid>

</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

Cartoons.xaml.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using Microsoft.Phone.Shell;
using SoundBoard.Resources;
using Coding4Fun.Toolkit.Audio;
using Coding4Fun.Toolkit.Audio.Helpers;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.IsolatedStorage;
using Coding4Fun.Toolkit.Controls;
using SoundBoard.ViewModels;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace SoundBoard
{
    public partial class Cartoons : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        private MicrophoneRecorder _recorder = new MicrophoneRecorder();
        private IsolatedStorageFileStream _audioStream;
        private string _tempFileName = "tempWav.wav";

        public Cartoons()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            DataContext = App.ViewModel;

            BuildLocalizedApplicationBar();
        }
            // Load data for the ViewModel Items
        protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!App.ViewModel.IsDataLoaded)
            {
                App.ViewModel.LoadData();
            }
        }

        private void LongListSelector_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            LongListSelector selector = sender as LongListSelector;

            // verifying our sender is actually a LongListSelector
            if (selector == null)
                return;

            SoundData data = selector.SelectedItem as SoundData;

            // verifying our sender is actually SoundData
            if (data == null)
                return;

            if (File.Exists(data.FilePath))
            {
                AudioPlayer.Source = new Uri(data.FilePath, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
            }
            else
            {
                using (var storageFolder = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
                {
                    using (var stream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(data.FilePath, FileMode.Open, storageFolder))
                    {
                        AudioPlayer.SetSource(stream);
                    }
                }
            }

            selector.SelectedItem = null;
        }

        private void BuildLocalizedApplicationBar()
        {
            ApplicationBar = new ApplicationBar();

            ApplicationBarIconButton recordAudioAppBar =
                new ApplicationBarIconButton();

            recordAudioAppBar.IconUri = new Uri("/Assets/AppBar/Save.png", UriKind.Relative);
            recordAudioAppBar.Text = AppResources.AppBarSave;

            recordAudioAppBar.Click += recordAudioAppBar_Click;

            ApplicationBar.Buttons.Add(recordAudioAppBar);
            ApplicationBar.IsVisible = false;

        }

        void recordAudioAppBar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            InputPrompt fileName = new InputPrompt();

            fileName.Message = "What should we call the sound?";

            fileName.Completed += FileNameCompleted;

            fileName.Show();

        }

        private void FileNameCompleted(object sender, PopUpEventArgs<string, PopUpResult> e)
        {
            if (e.PopUpResult == PopUpResult.Ok)
            {

                // Create a sound data object

                SoundData soundData = new SoundData();
                soundData.FilePath = string.Format("/customAudio/{0}.wav", DateTime.Now.ToFileTime());
                soundData.Title = e.Result;

                // Save the wav file into the DIR /customAudio/

                using (IsolatedStorageFile isoStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication()) {
                    if (!isoStore.DirectoryExists("/customAudio/"))
                        isoStore.CreateDirectory("/customAudio/");

                    isoStore.MoveFile(_tempFileName, soundData.FilePath);
                }


                // Add the SoundData to App.ViewModel.CustomSounds

                App.ViewModel.CustomSounds.Items.Add(soundData);

                // Save the list of CustomSounds to isolatedStorage.ApplicationSettings

                var data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(App.ViewModel.CustomSounds);

                IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings[SoundModel.CustomSoundKey] = data;
                IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Save();

                // We'll need to modify sound model to retrieve CustomSounds
                //from isolatedStorage.ApplicationSettings

                NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
            }
        }

        private void RecordAudioChecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            PlayAudio.IsEnabled = false;
            ApplicationBar.IsVisible = false;
            RotateCirlce.Begin();
            _recorder.Start();
        }

        private void RecordAudioUnchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            _recorder.Stop();

            SaveTempAudio(_recorder.Buffer);

            PlayAudio.IsEnabled = true;
            ApplicationBar.IsVisible = true;
            RotateCircle.Stop();
        }

        private void SaveTempAudio(MemoryStream buffer)
        {
            //defensive...
            if (buffer == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("Attempting a save on empty sound buffer.");

            //Clean out hold on audioStream
            if (_audioStream != null)
            {
                AudioPlayer.Stop();
                AudioPlayer.Source = null;

                _audioStream.Dispose();
            }

            var bytes = buffer.GetWavAsByteArray(_recorder.SampleRate);

            using (IsolatedStorageFile isoStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication()) {

                if (isoStore.FileExists(_tempFileName))
                    isoStore.DeleteFile(_tempFileName);

                _tempFileName = string.Format("{0}.wav", DateTime.Now.ToFileTime());


                _audioStream = isoStore.CreateFile(_tempFileName);
                _audioStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                //Play ...  SetSource of a mediaElement
                AudioPlayer.SetSource(_audioStream);

            }

        }

        private void PlayAudioClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            AudioPlayer.Play();
        }

    }
}
```

As I said it is probably something dumb but I am really stuck so would really appreciate any advice.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that all the problems reside in auto-generated files `Cartoons.g.cs`. The only error that points to non fully auto-generated file is this :

```
The name 'AudioPlayer' does not exist in the current context \SoundBoard\Cartoons.xaml.cs
```

Which complaining about `AudioPlayer` doesn't exists when it does exist, declared in Cartoons.xaml. So that's all weird errors.

First thing I will do is clean up (from visual studio, or manually delete `bin` and `debug` folders) and rebuild the project, and or even restart Visual Studio. Those steps can fix weird errors most of the time.

Comment: Thanks for your reply har07. I tried deleting the Bin folder and the debug folder but it just had the same errors. Just FYI there are three other very similar pages to cartoons, being animals, warnings, and taunts. The pages are all the same except have different sounds. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Forgot to mention, these other pages all have the same errors too.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that both `Cartoons.xaml` and `MainPage.xaml` have the same line `x:Class="SoundBoard.MainPage"`. I'm not sure but think that `Cartoons.xaml` should have different value for `x:Class` attribute